# Selenium Java click on a link to get to another page

Tags: selenium, redirect

My code initially goes to this page http://test1.absofttrainings.com, that is the url i have in my get(url) option. After going to this page on top there is TestPages which has an option Java Script, Alert,Confirm, Popup boxes.

Problem: I am trying to click that selection Java script from this page http://test1.absofttrainings.com and go to the Java script, Alert page.I am getting No such element error.

I tried waituntil visible, implicit wait nothing worked.

browserFunction("firefox", "http://test1.absofttrainings.com");

```
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait( 15, TimeUnit.SECONDS );

    driver.findElement(By.linkText("JavaScript Alert,Confirm,Prompt Boxes")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait( 15, TimeUnit.SECONDS );
    //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains("JavaScript Alert,Confirm,Prompt Boxes"));
```

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: To click on target link you should hover over `TestPages` element first. Show code you use to hover

Comment: Great I was not aware of that hover function, after doing some research I found about using Action, hopefully that will do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to hover the menu first, then the link you want will be exposed and you can click on it.

```
driver.get("http://test1.absofttrainings.com/");
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.linkText("Test Pages"))).build().perform();
driver.findElement(By.linkText("JavaScript Alert,Confirm,Prompt Boxes")).click();
```